# Injecting springSecurityService into Controller with Grails 3.0.3

Tags: spring, spring-security, spring-boot, grails-3.0

I am trying to get current user inside a controller in a Grails 3.0.3 application. 
I have used [this](https://github.com/dspies/grails-3-with-security) repo as a base for my security setup - security is GORM based. I am using following line in build.gradle in order to include Spring Security Framework:

```
compile "org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-security"
```

but when I try to inject springSecurityService like it was recommended in other SO threads (see for example: [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23279897/grails-spring-security-get-current-user)) in my controller, I get only a null object. It is not initiated like it should be.

```
class RestapiController {
    def springSecurityService

    def currentUser(){
        def user = springSecurityService.currentUser
        render user
    }
}
```

How can I inject springSecurityService into a controller in Grails 3.0.3?

UPDATE:
In the end I used following line to get the current user:

```
SecurityContextHolder.context.authentication.name
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`springSecurityService` isn't part of Spring Security, it's in the Grails spring-security-core plugin. Spring Security doesn't have the concept of the "current user". You can access the current `Authentication` and get the username, password, enabled, etc., but there's nothing in the framework that gets you back to the source object that was used to populate the authentication (in Grails + spring-security-core this is often a `User` domain class instance) - that would have to be done in your application code.

This weekend I released an initial version of the plugin that works with Grails 3, version 3.0.0.M1. The documentation is [here](https://grails-plugins.github.io/grails-spring-security-core/). There's a short tutorial in the docs to help get you started, and you might also check out [this sample app using the plugin in Grails 3](https://github.com/rmondejar/grails3-library-example).

Comment: Also note that if you only need this in a controller, you can skip injecting `springSecurityService` and use the [getAuthenticatedUser() metaclass method](https://grails-plugins.github.io/grails-spring-security-core/guide/controllerMetaClassMethods.html) that's injected into all controllers (or the analagous `authenticatedUser` property).

Comment: Thanks Burt! I also added an update with code I used in the end to get the name of the current user.

Comment: That's very different. `springSecurityService.currentUser` retrieves the domain class instance from the database, and should only be used when you need domain class data that isn't available from the `Authentication`. If you only need the username, then your code is fine, and a more compact option is `springSecurityService.principal.username`. If you can't dependency-inject `springSecurityService` then something is broken. Of course that's assuming that you're using the spring-security-core plugin - if you're using the Spring Boot starter, then yes, you have to do a lot more work in your app.