# How to get the current User object that is logged in grails?

Tags: grails, spring-security

i want to get the current user who is logged in and i used this way and i jave injected the SpringsecurityService and i am getting this error like "Caused by
No such property: principal for class: grails.plugin.springsecurity.SpringSecurityService Possible solutions: principal".

Organization.controller

```
SpringSecurityService springSecurityService

 def user = springSecurityService.get(SpringSecurityService.principal.id)
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Grails Spring Security (get current user)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23279897/grails-spring-security-get-current-user)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Inject springSecurityService and call getCurrentUser()

**Example:**

```
class OrganizationController {

    def springSecurityService
    def myAction(){
       User user = springSecurityService.getCurrentUser() //where "User" is is user domain class or you can "def" also
    }
}
```

}

`user` will hold your current logged in user object.

Hope this will helps you

Comment: thnk you.You really helped me today i have another probem too i ll post the link here and please see it

Comment: You can get user in gsp using `${applicationContext.springSecurityService.currentUser}`

Comment: i have recently created "new TrainUser(date:new Date(),user:user,training:trainingMain,status:true).save(flush: true, failOnError: true)" constructor and after this line of code i want the ID it has been stored. how to do it??

Comment: no its new question stackoverflow is not giving me to post until 90 min

Comment: `def user=new TrainUser(date:new Date(),user:user,training:trainingMain,status:true).save(flush: true, failOnError: true)` and get id using `user.id`

Comment: Please delete above and these comments if this works. we need to follow stackoveflow policies

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49873717/i-am-going-to-save-an-user-and-organization-object-in-database-but-it-is-not-ins please look this issue